# Location button in Android google maps

Tags: java, android

[cannot add location button to my current app .I am completely new to app development please help!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPMH1.jpg)

Comment: Please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Using map object call map.setlocationEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

To show location button on map

SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        supportMapFragment.getMap().getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        supportMapFragment.getMap().getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        supportMapFragment.getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);

you can change button position too.

View locationButton = ((View) supportMapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
        // position on right bottom
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        rlp.setMargins(0, 0, 180, 80);